# How to excute graphql query with okHttpClient?

Tags: java, graphql, httpclient, okhttp, aws-appsync

I have this query that is working on postman

```
    query  {
getInstallment(amount: "400", bin: "400000", userName: "guille") {
    cardBrand
}
}
```

But when I try to excute this payload with okHttpClient

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/graphql");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "query  {\n" +
            "getInstallment(amount: \"400\", bin: \"400000\", userName: \"sbernal\") {\n" +
            "    cardBrand\n" +
            "}}");
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://awsendpoint.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql")
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("x-api-key", "dket")
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    System.out.println(response.code());

}

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/graphql");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "query  {\n" +
            "getInstallment(amount: \"400\", bin: \"400000\", userName: \"guille\") {\n" +
            "    cardBrand\n" +
            "}}");
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://ziexbkvj5bghnnyicsbge737oa.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql")
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("x-api-key", "da2-7utq5lkg5zcllodmlzp66dd3vy")
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    System.out.println(response.code());



}}
```

I get a erro 400 , What im doing wrong ? should i use another httpclient ?

Comment: what error message you are receiving?
You could be json encode the payload before send it


```
String query = "query  {\n" +
            "getInstallment(amount: \"400\", bin: \"400000\", userName: \"guille\") {\n" +
            "    cardBrand\n" +
            "}}"
URLEncoder.encode(query)
```

Comment: @DhanialRizkyWiraPutra im getting a 400 (bad request)

Comment: Can you show a similar working example as a chrome command?

Answer (score 2):

There are possibly 2 problems (+ 1 deprecation  and 1 note):

1. I used "application/json" with success with appsync (but I did not try with "application/graphql"):

```java
    public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

2. The content of the body must be a Json serialised String:

```java
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{ \"query\": \"query  {\n" +
            "getInstallment(amount: \"400\", bin: \"400000\", userName: \"sbernal\") {\n" +
            "    cardBrand\n" +
            "}} }");
```

3. RequestBody.create used is now deprecated but you can put the Json String as first argument to remove the deprecation warning.
4. For completeness, note that several keys are available in the Json Object [query, operationName  and variables], ex:

```java
        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        json.addProperty("query", "mutation CreateAccount($name: String!) {\n"
        + "  createAccount(input: {name: $name}) {\n"
        + "    id\n"
        + "  }\n"
        + "}");
        json.addProperty("operationName", "CreateAccount");
        JsonObject variables = new JsonObject();
        variables.addProperty("name", "account1");
        json.add("variables", variables);
        
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(json.toString(), JSON);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was exploring similar thing and came across this question, since i am able to do it using **OKHttp** Client and its fairly straight forward, i would like to post the code here for others to make it easier to do it.

We can simulate it using the following Steps using OKHttp Client

- Initialize OKHttp Client
- Jsonify the Query String
- Create Json Objects and Initialize them if we want to pass any parameter value, like in this example i am sending cursor value.
- Create Request Body by initializing it with the necessary attributes
- Execute the Request using OkHttp Client instance.
- Get the Json Response and use the **.string()** method instead of **.toString()** method to store the json Response.

Please find below the code for fetching the Launch List details of Space Ship from Heroku App

```
public String getResponse() {
    
    String response = "";
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    try {
   
        String json = "query LaunchList($cursor: String) {\n"
        +"launches(after: $cursor) {\n"
        +    "cursor\n"
        +            "hasMore\n"
        +    "launches {\n"
        +        "id\n"
        +                "site\n"
        +        "mission {\n"
        +            "name\n"
        +            "missionPatch(size: SMALL)\n"
        +        "}\n"
        +    "}\n"
        +"}\n"
    +"}";


        jsonObject.put("query",json);
        JSONObject variables = new JSONObject();
        variables.put("cursor","");
        jsonObject.put("variables",variables);

        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(jsonObject.toString(), MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"));
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://apollo-fullstack-tutorial.herokuapp.com/graphql")
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();

        response = client.newCall(request).execute().body().string();
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        System.out.println(ioException.toString());
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer just missing the imports as usual, ty btw.